# "NULL pointer is passed" for detecting contours

Tags: c++, c, opencv

[The program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971093/better-algorithm-for-edge-filter-in-video-programming) I'm working on is a contour detection program which filter our the largest contour in the captured frame, paint it with red and print out the center coordinate of the object. Sometimes when I debug the program, I got this error message:

```
OpenCV Error: Null pointer (NULL array pointer is passed) in unknown function, file ......../array.cpp line 2382
```

I already searched the source of the problem and found out if the first(and the following) captured frame(s) have no contour detected in it (contour is NULL), the program will crash. Until now, I haven't found any solution to make this program to ignore the error until at least a contour is detected. So any clue on how to stop this problem from happening?

Thanks in advance. Cheers

P/S: After a contour is detected, the program will work just fine. Currently using OpenCV 2.4.2

Comment: But you do know which function call causes the error. So just add a NULL check before calling it. BTW, seeing some code would be good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code is linked at the word "The program" in the post. Could you explain more about NULL check? I don't quit get it.

Comment: I have to get my eyes checked. Anyway, I added an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest, that you forget processing of the frame if you cannot find a contour.

```
cvFindContours( src_gray, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), 
    CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, cvPoint(0,0));
if(contours==NULL)
   continue;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
CvSeq* largest_contour = NULL;
...
while (current_contour != NULL){
    double area = fabs(cvContourArea(current_contour,CV_WHOLE_SEQ, false));       
    if(area > largestArea){
        largestArea = area;
        largest_contour = current_contour;
    }
    current_contour = current_contour->h_next;
}
```

... you might end up with `largest_contour` equal to `NULL` if `current_contour` starts being itself `NULL` and there is no 'saving grace' from `contours2` (itself also `NULL` at the beginning of processing).

Later on, `contours` being `NULL` does not matter as it is "recovered" by `contours2`, as you noticed

> After a contour is detected, the program will work just fine

but at the *very first frame*, this can not happen.

Then, `largest_contour` never gets its initial `NULL` value changed.

I suspect that this doesn't sit well with the following line:

```
cvMoments(largest_contour, &moments, 1);
```

which I would then modify in

```
if (largest_contour)
    cvMoments(largest_contour, &moments, 1);
else
    continue; // loop to next frame
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried `continue` function like your suggestion and `if (contours == NULL)` line like @RichardSchneider 's suggestion but I got this error: `Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unregconized or unsupported array type)`. Also, I don't think `cvMoments` is the reason because I already tried this program without `cvMoments` function but still got the error message.

Comment: If you are not sure of what triggers the error, I'm afraid that the quickest way to debug this would be to add a `fprintf(stderr, "Now calling %s\n", "FUNCTION_NAME");` just before each call to a library function. Then you'll know for sure which call uses the bad pointer.

Comment: Silly me, I already found the `Bad flag` error source. The error has nothing to do with the contour. Now the program works just fine. Thank you