# Contour comparison in OpenCV (Convertion from C to C++)

Tags: c++, c, opencv, video-processing

I am still new in C++ and now I need to convert some parts from this [old program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971093/better-algorithm-for-edge-filter-in-video-programming) of mine from C to C++ because I want to apply `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` in my program since it only available in C++. Basically this program will detect contours from a video camera based on [background subtraction](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractormog2) and choose the largest contours available.

I have a problem particularly on this part (taken from the [old program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971093/better-algorithm-for-edge-filter-in-video-programming)):

```
double largestArea = 0;                    //Const. for the largest area
CvSeq* largest_contour = NULL;             //Contour for the largest area
while (current_contour != NULL){           //If the current contour available
    double area = fabs(cvContourArea(current_contour,CV_WHOLE_SEQ, false));   //Get the current contour's area as "area"    
    if(area > largestArea){            //If "area" is larger than the previous largest area
        largestArea = area;
        largest_contour = current_contour; 
    }
    current_contour = current_contour->h_next;  //Search for the next contour
}
```

This part is where the program will scan each contour available as `current_contour`, find its area and compare it to previous largest contour. My question is **how to get the `current_contour`, its area and jump to the next contour in C++?** Also, **what is indicated by `contours.size()` in C++?** Is it the number of contours scanned or the total area of the contours?

This is what I've done so far:

```
for(;;)
{
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    if( frame.empty() )
            break;
    image=frame.clone();
    mog(frame,foreground,-1);

    threshold(foreground,foreground,lowerC,upperC,THRESH_BINARY);
    medianBlur(foreground,foreground,9);
    erode(foreground,foreground,Mat());
    dilate(foreground,foreground,Mat());

    findContours(foreground,contours,CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);  

    if(contours.empty())
        continue;

//Starting this part
    double largest_area = 0;
    for(int i= 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
        double area = contourArea(contours);
        if(area >= largest_area){
            largest_area = area;
            largest_contours = contours;
        }
    }
//Until this part

    drawContours(image,largest_contours,-1,Scalar(0,0,255),2);

    imshow( "Capture",image );
    imshow("Contours",foreground);

    if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: The old program got some bugs in it but the algorithm works just fine. Free to as me if you need the updated program. Currently using OpenCV 2.4.3 + VS C++ 2010 Exp.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to everybody who're trying to help me but I already got the answer which is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582270/contour-is-not-equal-to-contouri). Still, for those how still don't know: **OpenCV in `C` IS NOT EXACTLY THE SAME AS OpenCV in `C++`**.

Comment: You can describe how you solved the problem and post it and accept it as an answer. That way we know that a. it is solved and b. how did you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of the code, where I am finding all contours on image and calcilate their perimeter and area:

```
IplImage* bin = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(_image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvConvertImage(_image, bin, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cvCanny(bin, bin, 50, 200);
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* contours=0;

//Number of all contours on image @contoursCont@
int contoursCont = cvFindContours( bin, storage,&contours,sizeof(CvContour),CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));
assert(contours!=0);

// iterate through all contours --> current = current->h_next
 for( CvSeq* current = contours; current != NULL; current = current->h_next )
 {
     //calculate perimeter and area of each contour
     double area = fabs(cvContourArea(current));
     double perim = cvContourPerimeter(current);
     cvDrawContours(_image, current, cvScalar(0, 0, 255), cvScalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 1, 8);
     //the rest code 
  }
```

From OpenCV documentation:

The function cvFindContours retrieves contours from the binary image and returns the number of retrieved contours. The pointer CvSeq* contours=0 is filled by the function. It will contain a pointer to the first outermost contour or NULL if no contours are detected (if the image is completely black). Other contours may be reached from first_contour using the h_next and v_next links.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the OpenCV codes is in `C` language. Moreover I already made the program to compare the area in `C` (Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971093/better-algorithm-for-edge-filter-in-video-programming)). Now I just need to convert it into C++ and that is my main question.